# IE8 After hiding content the height of the wrapper is still the same

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, height

### Foreword

I've come across one of those weird Internet Explorer things again, and I've hit a wall.
To be more precise, it's **IE8**. I've also tested in IE7, and there is no problem there, so there's something with IE8..

*Note that there is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yT7c2/6/) down the bottom of this post that reproduces my problem.*

---

### Quick explanation

I've got this `ul` that's being used to expand/contract content when clicking the `span.content_head`. By default, the content is first shown.

```html
<div id="spreadsheet_overview">
    <ul class="overview_list">
        <li>
            <div class="content_head">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
                Recipe calculation
                <div class="summation">
                    <span class="title">1 tablet cost:</span>
                    <span class="value">0.09360828</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">Lots of content</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$("div.content_head").click(function(e){
    $(this).next(".container").toggle();
    $("div.indicator",this).toggleClass("contracted");
});
```

---

### The problem

The problem occur when I click to contract. Let me first show you how it looks in Firefox, where it works.

[image]
The document consists of

- body - slightly dark gray
- wrapper, bright gray
- dividing column, dark gray
- more dividers, white

As you can see, the document ends after "recipe calculation", and the height of the document has adjusted and removed the vertical scrollbars.
The wrapper has also adjusted its height.

In Internet Explorer 8, however, when I do the same thing, the wrapper maintain its height as if the content was still shown. Why isn't it adjusting the height in IE?

[image]

I've checked, and the height remains exactly the same as before I hid the content.

If this is a CSS issue, which I am sure it is, what could it be?

---

### JSFiddle

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yT7c2/6/) that can reproduce my specific issue. I've tried to cut down the CSS enough to the elements only in this issue.
It's probably something I've done with the CSS/HTML.
Hopefully one of you can spot it, 'cause I sure as hell can't...

Clicking on "Recipe calculation" will hide the content, and you'll notice that the height is still the same. In IE8.

Appreciate the help!

### Edits

w3d pointed out that when toggling the `height: auto` attribute in the developer tools, will adjust the wrapper height. After further investigation, it does the same thing when I resize the window.

Comment: have you done any debugging? does IE show the relevant div to have a display:none property?

Comment: @maxedison Yes, it has the `display: none` property set.

Comment: Not sure if this is much help, but... in IE Developer Tools if you toggle the `height:auto` property on `id="spread_overview"` the height miraculously corrects itself!? `<rant>`IE Developer Tools is a right pain to use on an Iframed Document!`</rant>`

Comment: @w3d Maybe it's got something to do with that horrible `hasLayout` thing, I'll investigate further... `<rant>`The developers behind Internet Explorer should be shot for their crimes. I'm looking at _you_ **microsoft**!`</rant>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
.fix{display: inline-block;}
```

To:

```
.fix{display: block;}
```

IE doesn't know what inline-block is.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! Should've known that. It's weird though, how come IE7 has no problem with it?

Comment: It is odd. Especially when you look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html and see that IE8 supports inline-block but IE7/6 have issues with it.  Maybe there are some conflicting css properties that are throwing IE8 for a loop? I dunno, figuring out IE css issues can be very painful.

Comment: Hhhmm definitely odd! IE8 does know what inline-block is. IE7 would seem to have no problem with it because IE7 does not support `display:inline-block` on elements which are naturally block-level elements. You have this applied to a `div` so the style rule is ignored in IE7. But removing this rule altogether in IE8 does not seem to fix it either, you do have to explicitly set `display:block`!? As @zgood suggests, the combination of other rules could be a problem.

Comment: @w3d That's probably true. There's a bunch of CSS that's not being shown in the example, might be that I've got a conflict somewhere.

Comment: I think the entire hack for this was 

    .fix{
       display: inline;
zoom: 1;
}

Which should make this equivalent.